# Composer create-project symfony/skeleton new_project "4.0"

Tags: symfony, installation, composer-php

It installs:

Symfony 4.1.3 (kernel: src, env: dev, debug: true)

How do I get it to install exactly 4.0.*?

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton new_project "4.0" Installing symfony/skeleton (v4.0.0)
  - Installing symfony/skeleton (v4.0.0): Loading from cache Created project in aaaa Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Package operations: 22 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/flex (v1.0.89): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.9.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v4.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/routing (v4.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.9.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v4.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/debug (v4.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v4.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/finder (v4.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v4.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dependency-injection (v4.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/config (v4.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/cache (v4.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/framework-bundle (v4.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v4.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dotenv (v4.1.3): Loading from cache Writing lock file Generating autoload files Symfony operations: 4 recipes (df8c84407bbee5e3e826455e7bbdef65)
  - Configuring symfony/flex (>=1.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/framework-bundle (>=3.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/console (>=3.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/routing (>=4.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
```

Executing script cache:clear [OK] 
Executing script assets:install public [OK]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just installing as it is:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton new_project 4.0
```

it will install 4.1.3 and then changing in composer.json symfony/framework-bundle to "~4.0.0" and then composer update

Comment: Have a look at dmnptr's comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51753906/480702

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton new_project 4.0.*
```

More info in `composer` documentation - https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project

Also, Symfony 4.0.* is no longer maintained. Consider upgrading to 4.1

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried this before. This does not work. It still goes to 4.1.3.

I know it's no longer maintained. Have some other constraints than "it's maintained or it's not."

What does work:
Just installing  as it is, it will install 4.1.3 and then changing in composer.json  symfony/framework-bundle to "~4.0.0" and then composer update

Comment: Also the command you provided returns: 
**no matches found: 4.0.***

Comment: I figured it out - specifying the version number in the command above tells composer which version of `symfony/skeleton` to use. It does not affect the version of `symfony` being installed. `symfony/skeleton` requires `symfony/lts: ^4@dev`, which always pulls the latest version of `symfony` from `4.*` branch.