# Symfony 4 : Unable to decode a message from 643 client. ["clientId" => 643]

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I just created a project in symfony 4 : `composer create-project  symfony/website-skeleton symbnb`

And i want to start the server with this command : `php bin\console server:run`, but i got this error :

```
Command "server:run" is not defined. 
Do you want to run "server:dump" instead?  (yes/no) [no]:
```

so I enter yes and i get this error : 
[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3cON.png)

any help please

EDIT : output of php bin/console list

[output of php bin/console list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Mxq.png)

thank you in advance

Comment: I can see you are using xampp.I think what might happened is that you already have you xamp server working while you try to use the symfony one. But i'm not sure at all.

That being said, it's weid that you get a "server:run" is not defined. Are you sure you are using Symfony V4 ?

Comment: hi as i said i'm using symfony v4

Comment: Can you give the output of `php bin/console list` ?

Comment: i just edited the question and i added the output of php bin/console list

Comment: As I suspected and as the command show. You are not using Symfony V4 but Symfony V5.
Actually the V5 got barely realesed a week ago, I can't really help you with this version. But at least it explains why server run isn't running. I guess the command no longuer exist. I suggest you to look how to download symfony on an older version (the 4) in order to be able to use the server:run command. It might be possible too that the V5 has still some issues ? I don't know.

Comment: wich commande can i use to create symfony 4 project
because iam folowing a cours on udemy about version 4

Comment: The documentation I think is updated to consider V4 is the latest version, which isn't the case anymore. You can try this `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton PROJECT_NAME 4.4.0`

Comment: i got this error : [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package symfony/website-skeleton with version 4.4.0.

Comment: Hi thank you thsi worked for me  composer create-project symfony/skeleton new_project 4.0.*

:https://stackoverflow.com/a/51753906/11223421

Comment: Yes sorry that version 4.4.0 do not exist. Now I would recommend to follow the official documentation and going to Symfony 5. But if your documentation is for symfony 4 you kinda have to use a symfony 4 stack. Glad it helped you.

Comment: hi sorry it create a symfony 5 project and i got a 404 error ! [link](https://user.oc-static.com/upload/2019/11/29/15750466564931_Capture.PNG)

Comment: Try this one `composer create-project symfony/skeleton PROJECT_NAME 4.4.x-dev`

Answer (score 0):

In [symfony 4 server](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/setup/built_in_web_server.html) is not installed by default. What you need to do is easy:

- cd your-project/
- composer require --dev symfony/web-server-bundle
- php bin/console server:start